# How check radComboboxItem 'CheckBox'?

Tags: c#, checkbox, telerik, radcombobox

I have a little problem with the library 'Telerik'. 
Indeed I want to implement a 'RadCombobox "with' checkBox '. It works well, yet when I want
'Check' an item, it is impossible?! 
Here is my sample code. I changed the property of the attribute 'selected' but that does not check the box 'checked' unfortunately .....

Thank you very much for your answer!

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

//Define the sqlAdaptater for binding source

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter myBinding = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [name] FROM [dbo].[tblProcess] WHERE [currentVersion] = 1 AND [deleted] = 0 AND [parent] = 0",connectionString);

DataTable links = new DataTable();

myBinding.Fill(links);

//Set the attributs of RadCombobBox

RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.DataTextField = "name";
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.DataValueField = "name";
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.DataSource = links;

//Not working..its selected but not checked ?
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.SelectedIndex = 1;

//Not exist ?? -> 
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.CheckedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling the method `DataBind` first

```
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.DataBind();
```

After calling `DataBind` you could try this line of your code still not working,

```
RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.Items[1].Checked = true;
```

Comment: RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.Items[1].Checked -> does not exist in Telerik .. I have tested RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.DataBind(); 
after selectedIndex but not work .. :-(

Comment: @Mehdi Bugnard: I'm surprised that `RadComboBoxSelectedEntity.Items[1].Checked` doesn't exist (they do on ASP.NET Ajax Controls). Which Telerik controls are you using?

Comment: Yes but it work only with DataTemplate !               <ItemTemplate> 
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox" Checked="false"   Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Text") %>' />  
<asp:Label ID="lblSearchRef" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Text") %>' Visible="true" /> 
</ItemTemplate>